# Flickr API upload image to stream

Tags: php, flickr

Hi all i have a problem when uploading file to flickr

if i use the following code it works:

```
     <?php   $f = new phpFlickr($api_key,$secret);
     $result1 = $f->sync_upload("ico/20.jpg", $_POST["title"], $_POST["description"],    
      "david walsh, php, mootools, dojo, javascript, css");     

     ?>
```

i try to use a form to use the following code:

```
     <?php 
     if(isset($_POST['file']['name')){
     $result = $token_rsp->sync_upload($_POST["file"]["name"], $_POST["title"],     
     $_POST["description"],             "david walsh, php, mootools, dojo, javascript,  

     css");}
     ?>
```

it is not uploading and after i select a file to upload it opens the file dialog
again (5 times).this is my form:

```
     <form method="POST" name="zoe" enctype="multipart/form-data"
     target="myiframe1">
     <input type="file" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:50px;" name="file"
     id="file" value="upload"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000" />
     <input type="submit" id="submit" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:80px;"    
     value="Upload Imgur" />
     </form>
```

i hope i have the right syntax because i can't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly right, but you cannot use $_POST to access files. Multipart forms send through form data in $_POST, and file uploads in $_FILES.

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_FILES['file']['name')){
 $result = $token_rsp->sync_upload($_POST["file"]["name"], $_POST["title"],     
 $_POST["description"],             "david walsh, php, mootools, dojo, javascript,  

 css");}
 ?>
```

Check [this documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) out for more information.

Comment: The temporary filename after the upload is in `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`.

Comment: the strange thing is when i dont login to flickr on my page it only ask for a file once as soon as i am logged in in flickr it opens the file dialog 5 times and file keeps empty

Comment: Well i put the php code and the form to a new file.the if(isset catches the $_FILES[file][name] but it is not uploading the file to my flickr stream